# Woocommerce list terms by subcategories - Create a menu

Tags: woocommerce

So, I would like to get a list of Woocommerce attributes terms by category in order to create a header menu. I can list "attributes -> terms" and "product_cat -> id" with simple queries. But how can I manage to create a query that make a combination of them? Let me explain you more precisely what I want :

STRUCTURE OF PAGES
|> TL Lamps [-> a category] 
|=> T8 - T5 - etc [-> some subcategories] 
|==> Shop [-> All Products matching a subcategory] 
|==> Wattage | Size | Color | etc [-> Attributes containing terms linked to each products]

> How to get a list of those terms by their subcategories?

My final goal would be to get a top menu that contains (for instance) a submenu like this :

> TL Lamps => T8 => 14W | 18W | 24W

Where 14W | 18W | 24W are terms from the "Wattage" attribute. This menu would show terms like "childs" of T8 category. They would be produced and listed by the fact that they exists in the "T8" category, or to be more precise every product of "T8" category has at least one Wattage, so show this wattage.

Here is my basic code to show a list of all "wattage" terms and all subcategories of my website...

```
$watt_attribute = get_terms('pa_wattage'); //"Attribute -> Terms" list

foreach($watt_attribute as $watt_term) { // Show the list in links
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($watt_term->term_id).'" class="link-of-term"><span class="title-of-term">'.$watt_term->name.'</span></a><br>';
}

$product_cat = get_terms( 'product_cat',
    array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent'   => 0
    )
);


foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
{
    $child_args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
    );

    $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );

    foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
    {   
        //links of my subcategories
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id).'" class="link-of-subcat"><span class="title-of-subcat">'.$child_product_cat->name.'</span></a><br>';

    }
}
```

I'll buy a coffee to the one who makes me this possible! [OR help me to really go on]

peace!

Edit : By the title this is exactly what I would like to do, but it doesn't work at all... And this code seems way to advanced for me to understand. Here : 
[Dynamically Populate WooCommerce Product Category Terms To Wordpress Navigation Menu](https://phpsmashcode.com/tips-and-tricks/dynamically-populate-woocommerce-product-category-terms-wordpress-navigation-menu)

Comment: You can't link 2 different custom taxonomies together (meaning "parent" vs "child"… so product attributes are independent from product category terms… Product category and product attributes are different custom taxonomies (Remember that each product attribute is a custom taxonomy itself) … Also product attributes terms don't handle term link… **So your Product attributes terms from "pa_wattage" taxonomy will never be childs from a product category term**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time! OK I know that. But here is my point, when I go on my website, through my shop [a category in the shop on this particular case] I've a sidebar with filters, those filters going hidden/shown by the fact they match or not the shown products... So, if I'm on the "T8" category, then the filters match exactly all the [Attribute->]terms I wanted from "pa_wattage" [and so on for every others attribute->terms]... I can't understand that... I mean if it's possible on the shop page why it would be impossible on the header? I know it's "archive" related but can't figure out what